# How do you play a sound in c# based on a multiple variable condition?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an alarm to go with my binary clock for my final project in intro to programming.

I already made the controls, have an intAlarmHour and intAlarmMinute value. I've found some articles on playing sounds in C#, but the code isn't quite working for me. This is what I have so far, under timer1:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == intAlarmHour && DateTime.Now.Minute == intAlarmMinute)
        System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(//unknown format);
sound.PlaySync();
```

I'm getting

Error   1   Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement C:\ADixon\Final\Binary Project\BinaryClock\BinaryClock\Form1.cs 551 13  BinaryClock

Error   2   Use of unassigned local variable 'sound'    C:\ADixon\Final\Binary Project\BinaryClock\BinaryClock\Form1.cs 552 1   BinaryClock

I'm also not 100% on the format of the sound file. I assume I throw it in system resources within the project and link to it like I would a picture? What is it, form1.system.resources.file ?

And if I use the System.Media.SoundPlayer method, what file types are allowed? Can I use .mp3?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is 'lack of curly braces'. An 'If' statement without curly braces will only run the next line following it. So in your case, because the 'sound' declaration is conditional and contained within the 'if' statement, your 'sound.Play()' is unassigned.

Should be:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == intAlarmHour && DateTime.Now.Minute == intAlarmMinute)
{
     System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(//unknown format);
     sound.PlaySync();
}
```

Comment: I got rid of all the errors by adding the braces and taking out the fill-in //unknown format... would throwing an mp3 in the resources folder and throwing form1.system.resources.whatever in the () work to actually link the sound?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a .wav file.  You can make it an embedded resource which means it will be bundled inside the exe itself.

Click on Project --> Properties --> Resources Tab --> Add Resource --> Add Existing File --> Double Click the .wav file.
In the Properties Pane (bottom right), change "Persistence" to "Embedded in .resx".

Now you can use code like this to play the sound:

```
        // where "buzzer" below will be the name of the .wav YOU added:
        System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.buzzer);
        sound.Play();
```